# Cannot read property 'getElementAtEvent' of undefined, Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I am getting this error when trying to call a function of chart using chart.js, this is how the code looks like, simplified:

```
export class TrackerPage {
  @ViewChild('doughnutCanvas') doughnutCanvas;
  doughnutChart: any;

  this.doughnutChart = new Chart(this.doughnutCanvas.nativeElement, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: this.titles,
    datasets: [{
      data: this.times,  
    }]
  },
  options: {
    onClick: this.timeSlotEdit,
  }
});

  timeSlotEdit(event, array){
    let activeElement = this.doughnutChart.getElementAtEvent(event);
    console.log(activeElement);
```

When I try to `console.log(this.doughnutChart)` inside of `timeSlotEdit()` function it returns `'undefined'`. Doing the same in another not related function returns full chart info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are losing the `this` context if you are using a callback like that. You should wrap it in an anonymous arrow function wrapper, or use `bind`. Also the chart initialization is called too soon. You have to use the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle-hook to be sure that your canvas is inside the HTML:

```
export class TrackerPage {
  @ViewChild('doughnutCanvas') doughnutCanvas;

  doughnutChart: Chart;

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.doughnutChart = new Chart(this.doughnutCanvas.nativeElement, {
       type: 'doughnut',
       data: {
         labels: this.titles,
         datasets: [{
           data: this.times,  
         }]
       },
       options: {
          onClick: this.timeSlotEdit.bind(this),
       }
    });
  }

  timeSlotEdit(event, array){
    let activeElement = this.doughnutChart.getElementAtEvent(event);
    console.log(activeElement);
  }
}
```

With an anonymous arrow function:

```
onClick: (event, array) => {this.timeSlotEdit(event, array)},
```

Another way is to keep it the way you had it before, but change the `timeSlotEdit` to this:

```
timeSlotEdit = (event, array) => {

}
```

this is particularly useful for unbinding events, because you can use the function reference to remove the event listener.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, could you show me how it should look like using anonymous arrow function?